# Set a textfield and then edit it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, variables, uitextfield

**How can i set the value of a textfield and then edit it?** Using firebase, I created a dictionary for a user account that contains a name. For the first textfield, the textfield text is equal to the user's name. When the user begins to edit the name using through that textfield, another variable called "username" should store the new text/value, but it doesn't. The user can edit the textfield itself, but the "username" variable doesn't store the edited version, only the original version (user.name) thats stored in firebase. Here's my code below:

```
            var username: String?
            case 0:
                firstfewCells.ttField.text = user.name
                self.username = firstfewCells.ttField.text
```

What I want to do is make the textfield editable so that whatever is in the textfield when the save button is pressed, will be stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the value of `username` to `user.name` but in all likelihood that value is a copy and you shouldn't expect changes to the 'username' to result from changes to the textfield.

There are ways for you to listen to changes to the textfield, the simplest being through the `uitextfielddelegate` method `textfielddidchange` (I'll leave it to you to google).

However, what I recommend you do, if you just want to provide a form-like interface to allow a user to change values that will then be POSTed to a server is to simply grab the values of the text fields when the save or submit button is pressed (`let username = nameTextField.text`). This simplifies your code in that you will eliminate unneeded state and all complexity that would come with keeping it in sync.

Comment: how could I go about doing that when the textfields are placed within a tableview and Im accessing each textfield at cellForRowAt by their index path?

Comment: @Vandal Ok so this is a little more complicated and there are a few ways to do this.   You can create your textfields in your view controller and keep references to them and add them (and remove them) to their appropriate cells (contentview) in 'cellforindexpath' implementation. Or do as I said above - use the textfielddelegate protocol to listen to changes and update a separate string. You will probably use 'tableview indexpathForCell' to figure out which string should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
       var name : String? 

 override func awakeFromNib() {
           yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.doSomething(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
       }

        func doSomething() {
           yourTextField.text
        }
```

If you want to send this info to your ViewController, You need to create a delegate. If you need with that, you can ask. But there are quite a few tutorials explaining how it works.

Comment: You can also do what alex suggested by extending your custom cell to follow the "UITextFieldDelegate" methods. 

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate

Explains everything you can do with it. :)